# Django Session store all sessions

Tags: django

I am storing django sessions on disk. I have a particular case where I need to go through each session and delete certain keys and keep the rest. So clearing the entire cache isn't an option. I was able to iterate over individual sessions when sessions were in db. But with session store I am stuck. what I need to do is similar to this:

```
    sessions=sessionstore.all()
    for session in sessions:
      session.pop('key1')
      session.pop('key2')
      if session lastmodified before some time:
        del session
```

Answer (score 1):

Look how iteration is done in the clear_expired method in django.contrib.sessions.backends.file:

```
@classmethod
def clear_expired(cls):
    storage_path = cls._get_storage_path()
    file_prefix = settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME

    for session_file in os.listdir(storage_path):
        if not session_file.startswith(file_prefix):
            continue
        session_key = session_file[len(file_prefix):]
        session = cls(session_key)
        # When an expired session is loaded, its file is removed, and a
        # new file is immediately created. Prevent this by disabling
        # the create() method.
        session.create = lambda: None
        session.load()
```